# How to use OAuth2RestTemplate with Spring Authorization Code Flow

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I can not figure out how to use thoso two together. After user is authenticated, I have OAuth2AuthorizedClient in the context which then I can use like:

```
String clientRegistrationId = auth.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId();
OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = clientService.loadAuthorizedClient(clientRegistrationId, auth.getName());
accessToken = client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
```

So I can use accessToken in my application. But this is manual interceptor that I inject into RestTemplate. Also if I do this way than I have to handle all refreshToken logic with another interceptor. Here then comes OAuth2RestTemplate, it handles all accessToken, refresToken stuff which I don't need interceptors. But to use it I need OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails:

```
public OAuth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource) {

    this(resource, new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext());
}
```

which I don't if I use spring.security.oauth2.client.registration style. Because AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails created only if security.oauth2.client style is used.:

```
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          example-authorization-code:
            id: demo-webapp-oidc-code
            client-id: demo-webapp-oidc-code
            client-secret: secret
            client-name: demo-webapp-oidc-code
            provider: authServer
            redirect-uri: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-authentication-method: post
            scope: openid, address
        provider:
          authServer:
            token-uri: http://localhost:8095/authServer/oidc/token
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:8095/authServer/oidc/authorize
            user-info-uri: http://localhost:8095/authServer/oidc/profile
            jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8095/authServer/oidc/jwks
            user-name-attribute: id
```

This is how It accepts:

```
@Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "security.oauth2.client")
    @Primary
    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails oauth2RemoteResource() {
        return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    }
```

I can create it manually but than things getting complicated. Lets imagine somehow I created resourceDetails, than I create OAuth2RestTemplate with fllowing,

```
new OAuth2RestTemplate( resourceDetails, defaultOAuth2ClientContext);
```

which means I need to set new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext:

```
public DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken) {
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
    this.accessTokenRequest = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();
}
```

which requires Oauth2AccessToken. But I have **core.OAuth2AccessToken** in my context ( OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient.getAccessToken), while it requires **common.OAuth2AccessToken.**